# Problem in building gcc 4.5 : error in tools.zip

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, build

I tryied to build gcc 4.5.0 on Linux version 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5, and found the following problems that I couldn't find an answer on Google. I used the following command.

../gcc-4.3.5/configure --prefix=/usr --prefix=/apps --with-gmp=/apps --with-mpc=/apps --with-mpfr=/apps --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix
make -j 8

Here is the part when it complained about the error

...

cp: preserving ACL for `./asm/org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter.class': Operation not supported

cp: preserving permissions for `./asm/org/objectweb/asm': Operation not supported

cp: preserving permissions for `./asm/org/objectweb': Operation not supported

cp: preserving permissions for `./asm/org': Operation not supported

cp: preserving permissions for `./asm': Operation not supported

make[6]: *** [tools.zip] Error 1

make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath/tools'

make[6]: Entering directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath'

true  DO=all multi-do # make

make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath'

make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava/classpath'

make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libjava'

make[3]: *** [multi-do] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'

make[2]: *** [all-multi] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libjava'

make[1]: *** [all-target-libjava] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gl/gcc4.3obj'

make: *** [all] Error 2

Any clarification and help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're building gcc 4.5.0 but your error messages and ./configure line suggest that you are instead building gcc 4.3.5.  I point this out because it's possible you have tripped over a bug in gcc 4.3.x's build scripts.

Second, the error messages you quoted make me think that you are doing your build on a weird file system, or else you have a buggy `cp` (unlikely but not impossible).  What sort of file system is /home?  You can find out with the `mount` command -- type it with no arguments, look for the /home line, see what it says next to "type".  I have this:

```
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

ext2, ext3, ext4, btrfs, xfs, and jfs should not be troublesome; anything else might well be for this use.

By the way, the precise version of your kernel ("Linux version 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5") is very unlikely to be relevant; for this sort of problem it would be much more useful to know which distribution you are using, and the version of that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 

You were right, it's 4.3.5, but the same problems happened when I tried to build 4.5.0 in another directory at the beginning, and then I downloaded 4.3.5 to have another try.

Here is the output from mount,
nfs-1:/p0/home/gl on /home/gl type nfs (rw,addr=10.1.0.3)

The distribution is from redhat
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: NFS? Oho.  Are you doing your build as root?  Never do that.  Always compile and test as a normal user; only do `make install` as root.  This is not just for safety - lots of projects' build systems break (as you have seen) if you run the compilation phase as root, especially if you're working out of NFS, which normally maps root-on-the-client to a totally unprivileged user ID on the server.  (By the way, your build will be *orders of magnitude* faster if you put the build directory on a local disk.  It's okay to have the source on NFS.)

Comment: No. I am not the root, and that's why I have to specify the prefix in configure. 

I connect to the server as a normal user, and so I have access only to /apps and my home directory.

Do you think the cp command is the reason for the error?

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible that the real error is some way above the errors you quoted.  But the first thing I would try is putting the build directory on a local disk.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the write access to other disks on the server.    I will see if there is another way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem building a different package (LAMMPS). The Makfile included a -p flag in a cp statement. I removed it and the error disappeared. It may be worth a try...